# how to make my input accept empty value or number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, input

I want to make 2 inputs, one for a *min* value, one for a *max* value.

I managed to make a resuable component and to make it accept the `min` and `max` value I want, but now I can't delete the data to write another one.

If i delete the value, `0` is set.

How to accept empty value or number from 0 to 5 ?

Thanks

```
const FilterAnnonceNombrePiece = () => {
  const [filtresMax, setFiltresMax] = useAtom(numberPiecesMax);
  const [filtresMin, setFiltresMin] = useAtom(numberPiecesMin);

  const minValue = 0;
  const maxValue = 5;

  const setNumberPiecesMin = (value: number | string) => {
    setFiltresMin(numberWithMinMaxDefaultValue(value, minValue, maxValue, minValue));
  };

  const setNumberPiecesMax = (value: number | string) => {
    setFiltresMax(numberWithMinMaxDefaultValue(value, minValue, maxValue, maxValue));
  };

  const numberWithMinMaxDefaultValue = (
    value: number | string,
    minValue: number,
    maxValue: number,
    defaultValue: number,
  ): number => {

  const res = typeof value === 'number' ? value : parseFloat(value);
  const emptyString = value === '';

    if (emptyString) {
      return defaultValue;
    }

    if (isNaN(res)) {
      return defaultValue;
    }

    if (res < minValue) {
      return minValue;
    }

    if (res > maxValue) {
      return maxValue;
    }

    return res;
};

  return (
      <div className="hk-flex hk-flex-row hk-gap-1.5">
        <InputFloatingLabel
          label="min"
          value={filtresMin}
          onChange={setNumberPiecesMin}
          inputProps={{ type: 'text' }}
        />
        <InputFloatingLabel
          label="max"
          value={filtresMax}
          onChange={setNumberPiecesMax}
          inputProps={{ type: 'text' }}
        />
      </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: When you debug, is this producing the `0`?: `return defaultValue;`

Comment: @David you are totally right. I added a condition in the function (see edited code), but I still get a '0' if I delete the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of functions I recommend using [guard clauses](https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2020-01/guard-clauses/).

Instead of returning the `defaultValue` you can return a empty string when the value is a empty string. This way you can change your value in the input without compromising on the min/max logic. Since this is a controlled input you actually can't return 0 / the default input since this wont allow to, like you said erase the value

```js
const numberWithMinMaxDefaultValue = (
  value: number | string,
  minValue: number,
  maxValue: number,
  defaultValue: number
) => {
  // if empty return default value
  // if (value === "") return defaultValue;
  if (value === "") return "";

  // convert value of string to number / float
  if (typeof value === "string") {
    value = parseFloat(value);
  }

  // check for the thresholds
  if (value < minValue) return minValue;
  if (value > maxValue) return maxValue;

  // if no cases match the value is valid and we can return
  return value;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tried it, but I still get the 0 when I erase the value

Comment: @Johan you're correct, I've updated my answer now it returns a empty string when the value is a empty string. This way you can change your value in the input without compromising on the min/max logic. Since this is a controlled input you actually can't return 0 / the default input since this wont allow to, like you said erase the value.